# Looping through folders in a directory and subfolders

Tags: powershell

I have a directory with the following folder structure:

> - BookingService
>
>   - DEV
>
>     - BookingService.config
>   - UAT
>
>     - BookingService.config
>   - LIVE
>
>     - BookingService.config
> - DriverService
>
>   - DEV
>
>     - DriverService.config
>   - UAT
>
>     - DriverService.config
>   - LIVE
>
>     - DriverService.config
> - AccountService
>
>   - DEV
>
>     - AccountService.config
>   - UAT
>
>     - AccountService.config
>   - LIVE
>
>     - AccountService.config

I want to loop through each folder and the underlying DEV, UAT, LIVE subfolder to extract the contents of the *.config file.

I have tried the following so far, but keep getting the error message: `Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null`. How do I fix it?

```
$branch = "C:\work\Services"
$targetEnv = "DEV"

Get-ChildItem -Path $branch | % { 
    cd $_.DirectoryName 
    . $_.FullName 
    ($path = Resolve-Path "$($_.DirectoryName\($targetEnv)*\*.config") 2> $null
    if ($path -ne $null)
    {
        # do some stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` has a `-recurse` parameter. Why do you try to dot include the directory?

Comment: So should the command be `Get-ChildItem -Path $branch -recurse`? Dotted the directory as I got rather confused trying to set it up

Comment: You can also add the `-filter` parameter to filter for `.config` files,
so `Get-ChildItem -Path $branch -Recurse -Filter "*.config"` will give you an array containing FileInfo-Objects of all of your config files

Comment: @J.Bergmann what if I am only interested in a batch of `.config` files from a particular environment ie DEV, UAT or LIVE?

Comment: You can wildcard parts of your path. i.e. `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Work\Services\*\DEV -Recurse` will return the contents from all the DEV folders

Comment: @J.Bergmann how would the full code snippet look like? Like this: `et-ChildItem -Path $branch\*\DEV -Recurse | % { 
    cd $_.DirectoryName 
    . $_.FullName 
    ($path = Resolve-Path "$($_.DirectoryName\($targetEnv)*\*.config") 2> $null`

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with these files?